# dictionary size changed during iteration (Runtime error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I get RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration, I went through some of the stack overflow posts and found this happens when you modify the size of the dictionary while it loops (insert/delete).

However in my case I am just iterating over the dictionary so I am not sure why I get the error.

I found that when using the non collections dictionary I didn't get any issues, but that made adding new vertices much much more complex than using collections.

I know I could probably make a deep copy of dictionary and iterate over that but I want to first understand why I get this error in the first place.

I cut most of the non essential code in the example below.

```py
from collections import defaultdict 


class Graph: 

    def __init__(self,vertices): 

        self.graph = defaultdict(list)  

    def addEdge(self,u,v): 
        self.graph[u].append(v) 

    def fillOrder(self,v,visited, stack): 

        visited.add(v)
        for neighbour in self.graph[v]:
          if neighbour not in visited:
            self.fillOrder(neighbour, visited, stack)
        stack.append(v)


    def printSCCs(self): 

        stack = [] 

        visited = set()

        for key in self.graph:
          print(key)
          self.fillOrder(key, visited, stack)

g = Graph(5) 
g.addEdge(1, 0) 
g.addEdge(0, 2) 
g.addEdge(2, 1) 
g.addEdge(0, 3) 
g.addEdge(3, 4) 
g.printSCCs()
```

I expect no error to be thrown and the stack to be filled with the vertices in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `defaultdict` so there in an implict insert if you try to access an entry which doesn't exist.

In particular:

```
def fillOrder(self,v,visited, stack): 
    # ...
    for neighbour in self.graph[v]:
        # ...
```

Your key `v` isn't guaranteed to exist, so the access of `self.graph[v]` is causing a new  entry to be added to the dictionary. If you replace the `defaultdict` with a normal dictionary and create the new lists on demand in `addEdge` it's more obvious what's failing:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    g.printSCCs()
  File "test.py", line 30, in printSCCs
    self.fillOrder(key, visited, stack)
  File "test.py", line 21, in fillOrder
    self.fillOrder(neighbour, visited, stack)
  File "test.py", line 21, in fillOrder
    self.fillOrder(neighbour, visited, stack)
  File "test.py", line 21, in fillOrder
    self.fillOrder(neighbour, visited, stack)
  File "test.py", line 19, in fillOrder
    for neighbour in self.graph[v]:
KeyError: 4
```

If you want to guarantee both edge end points are in the dictionary you probably want to modify `addEdge` to do this:

```
self.graph[u].append(v) 
self.graph[v].append(u)
```

Comment: I call FillOrder from printSCC, within there is the loop, that goes over each key in self.graph, so how is it possible that v does not exist ?

Comment: When you add edges with end points "U" and "V" you only add "U" to the dictionary. You iterate both "U" and "V" so any edge where "V" isn't also added in another edge as a "U" value will fail.